# Determine $x$ and $y$ such that occurrences $\{u_1, u_2 \}$ and $\{u_2, u_3 \}$ are independent.

Tags: probability

I apologize that I do not use the proper mathematical terms here. I am not a native english speaker, and raw translation does not always work. Please do comment if it results in this being unintelligible.

In my math class an assignment goes:

```
A probability distribution is given by:

 - P(u1) = 0.3
 - P(u2) = x 
 - P(u3) = 0.2 
 - P(u4) = y

Determine x and y, such that the occurrences {u1, u2} and {u2, u3} are independent.
```

How can I determine $x$ and $y$?

---

**What have I tried?**

Not a lot really, I'm at a complete loss here. All I know is that $A$ is said to be independent if:

```
P(A|B) = P(A)
```

Although I have no idea how I would apply this knowleagde to the occurrences above.

I also realize the sum of the individual probabilities must be $1$, so $x+y = 0.5$, and thus solving either will give me the answer to the other, but this doesn't help as I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: I don't understand how at the same time $P(u_3) = 0.2$ and  $P(u_3) = y$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh, heh.  I completely overlooked that myself.  I suspect that the second occurrence should have been $P(u_4)$ instead.  That was how I read it and answered below.

Comment: That was indeed an error, I fixed it now haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want $\{u_1,u_2\}$ and $\{u_2,u_3\}$ to be independent.  Yes, this means that $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$, but reworded and rearranged, this means that we want $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$.

We have $P(\{u_1,u_2\}\cap\{u_2,u_3\})=P(\{u_2\})=x$

We further have $P(\{u_1,u_2\}) = 0.3+x$ and $P(\{u_2,u_3\})=0.2+x$

We want then for $x=(0.3+x)\cdot(0.2+x)$ or rewritten $x=0.06+0.5x+x^2$

Rearranging, $x^2-0.5x+0.06=0$ and so using the quadratic formula we can find $x=0.3$ or $x=0.2$

Indeed, checking we find that either are valid.  Once knowing $x$, we know that $y$ must be the other value as they should add up to $0.5$.

Comment: Thank you for the response @JMoravitz. I am still having trouble however. I don't see how P({u1,u2}∩{u2,u3})=P({u2}). Would you mind elaborating this? I have accepted the answer still, as im sure it all makes sense.

Comment: @cortex the symbol $\cap$ refers to set intersection, the result of which is the set of elements which are in both sets. In other words, this is the probability of both A and B happening simultaneously. For that to happen, that means that it was $u_2$ that happened as that is the only outcome that is in both events.

Comment: Ahh, cheers mate!